# Converting from ms database to MySQL between two dates issue

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

I'm converting ms to MySQL and have the following problem, here is my ms query:

```
FROM `history_card`
GROUP BY `history_card`.`SERIAL_NUMBER`
HAVING (((LAST(`history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE`)) Between Date() And Date()-60))
ORDER BY LAST(`history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE`) DESC;
```

it gives me 13 records
here is MySQL:

```
FROM `history_card`
GROUP BY `history_card`.`SERIAL_NUMBER`
HAVING (((MAX(`history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE`)) BETWEEN  (MAX(`history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE`)) AND DATE_ADD((MAX(`history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE`)), INTERVAL -60 DAY) ))
ORDER BY MAX(`history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE`) DESC;
```

so the problem is with BETWEEN , how can I make Mysql equivalent of : `Between Date() And Date()-60)` I tried this:

```
BETWEEN  (MAX(`history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE`)) AND DATE_ADD((MAX(`history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE`)), INTERVAL -60 DAY)
```

but It does not return any records

Comment: Try to write something that compiles first. `Date()` isn't a T-SQL function. Also try to fix the query itself. Filtering in the `HAVING` clause forces a full table scan in both databases. Are you looking for the *last* entry per serial number that falls into a range? Why not use a `WHERE ` then?

Comment: yes I want to get last entries, should I use WHERE instead of HAVING?

Comment: Date() in ms access returns the current date. In MySQL the curdate() function does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want (changing the format for clarity):

```
     FROM  `history_card`
 GROUP BY  `history_card`.`SERIAL_NUMBER`
   HAVING  MAX( `history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE` )
              BETWEEN CURDATE() 
              AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL -60 DAY )     
 ORDER BY  MAX( `history_card`.`DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE` ) DESC;
```